# Content exceeds container in low resolutions

Tags: html, responsive-design, wysiwyg, markup

I have a web page with services for several provinces in Spain. I have detected that in one of them, a container have been overlaped by it content whereas in other services it doesnt ocurr. All of them have same markup by changing content in each case which is a wysiwyg.

You can checkout both version above:

**Bug one**
[image]
https://lorraine.es/diseno-web/diseno-web-malaga/

**Good one**
[image]
https://lorraine.es/diseno-web/diseno-web-sevilla/

Do you know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the problem is that you have non-breaking spaces or ( `&nbsp;` characters) between the place names.

[image: non breaking spaces between place names]

If you replace these characters with regular spaces, all will be well ;)

[image: regular spaces between the place names]